Labels of a dash dccRangerSlider
I am trying to format the numbers shown on a dccRangeSlider. Right now I have a list of dates (a sample below).
dates= ['2004-Oct-01',
 '2004-Oct-08',
 '2004-Oct-15',
 '2004-Oct-22',
 '2004-Oct-29',
 '2004-Nov-05',
 '2004-Nov-12']


and I want to use the dccRangeSlider to show them.
I feel like i am missing something obvious (or maybe too tired).
Thanks any feedback appreciated.
As of now I have
    dcc.RangeSlider(0, 1021, value=[20,100],
        marks={
            0: {'label': dates[0], 'style': {'color': '#77b0b1'}},
            3: {'label': dates[3]},
            500: {'label': dates[0]},
            1021: {'label': dates[0], 'style': {'color': '#f50'}}
        },
        tooltip={"placement": "bottom", "always_visible": True},
        included=False
    )


So I get this:

But instead of 20 and 100 I would like to see dates[20] and dates[100]
I have tried transform but the sample given by plotly looks non-python
**
window.dccFunctions = window.dccFunctions || {};
window.dccFunctions.temperatureInCelsius = function(value) {
     return ((value - 32) * 5/9).toFixed(2);
}**

dcc.RangeSlider(
    0,
    10,
    value=[3, 7.65],
    marks={0: "0°F", 3: "3°F", 5: "5°F", 7.65: "7.65°F", 10: "10°F"},
    tooltip={"always_visible": True, "transform": **"temperatureInCelsius"}**,
)

Dashboard works fine but just makes sense to show dates in the format '2004-Oct-08' instead of "1".
I found a link prev problem but looks like it's been a while and no one has been able to find a good solution.

Hey, I think it is java as written in the example on dash tutorial page. if you can'T code that perhaps just don't put the tooltip there but just use the markerlabel. cheers
